# Cleaning the left side of an image

Tags: imagemagick

Using imagemagick, I want to clean the left side of an image, i.e. make white without cropping. For example cleaning the left-most vertical strip of 25 pixels wide. I figured out how to crop to a given geometry, but I couldn't figure out how to clean without cropping.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my start image, made like this:

```
convert -size 256x256 gradient:cyan-yellow image.png
```

[image]

#### Method 1

One way to do it would be to use `-fx` and set all pixels where the x-coordinate is less than 25 to 1.0 (i.e. white) and leave all other pixels as they are:

```
convert image.png -fx "i<25?1:u" result.png
```

[image]

### Method 2

Another, faster way to do it might be to clone the original image, and scale it down to 25 pixels wide, fill it with white and composite that over the original image:

```
convert image.png \
   \( +clone -scale 25x! -fill white -colorize 100  \) \
   -composite result.png
```

The result is the same.

### Method 3

A third way to do it might be to crop the image 25 pixels in from the left side, then splice 25 white pixels back on the left side:

```
convert image.png -crop +25+0 -background white -gravity west -splice 25x result.png
```

### Method 4

Bit of a kludge, but nearer to what you asked. Here, I guess that your image height doesn't exceed 10,000 pixels and draw a rectangle:

```
convert image.png -fill white -draw "rectangle 0,0 24,9999" result.png
```

I guess the *proper* way to do this is to get the height first then use it:

```
#!/bin/bash
h=$(convert image.png -format "%[fx:h-1]" info:)
convert image.png -fill white -draw "rectangle 0,0 24,$h" result.png
```